# Azure Hybrid Connection to API hosted on Websphere (on premise)

Tags: azure, websphere, azure-api-management, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an API that is hosted on Websphere Application Server (bound to a specific port), on a Windows 2012 R2 Server (on-prem), that I would like to expose to Azure API Management in the cloud. Ideally, the plan was to use Azure Hybrid Connections. Is that even possible? How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Azure Website and use the Hybrid Connection feature to expose your API via a simple WebApi Controller.

API Management will just talk to the Azure Website. You can limit access to the Azure Website from only the Public IP address of the API Management.

Comment: It seems like the service connects via Hybrid Connection Manager, I just cannot add it to API Management for some reason.

Comment: Additionally, I am not looking to rewrite the API that is already installed by the vendor. Are you suggesting I create another API, that "wraps" around the vendor API?